# how to show text in a button with css

Tags: css, z-index

I´ve got the following code:

### jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9b3YG/

### html

```
<a class="button" href="">
        <span class="fill_link"></span>
        Test
    </a>
```

and I want that the text of the link is in front of the span "fill_link", but i only can change the css of the class "button" and the class "fill_link".

Thanks

Comment: How about putting the text into another span and having full control of it

Comment: I know, but I want to keep it simple in the backend, so that the writer only needs to create a link and give that link a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set

```
z-index: -9999;
```

for the fill_link class.

[edited in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9b3YG/6/)

Comment: yes. i only tested it. you can use any minus number for z-index and it still working. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap text `<span class="text">Test</span>` and apply z-index for it. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/9b3YG/2/)